# Idiomatic way to write concurrent downloader in Scala

Tags: scala

In Python, I would typically use a queue from the standard library (which is thread-safe), and write a function that consumes an url from the queue, and saves the downloaded content to disk. I would spawn a few of these functions inside threading.Threads. If the download fails, I'd put the same url again in the queue.

What would be an idiomatic way to write a similar concurrent downlaoder in Scala? Which abstractions should I use?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options for this task:

- using `Future` combinators (this is pretty low level IMHO)
- using actors with `Akka` toolkit (I would use this)

You can have a look at this example project [Akka downloader](https://github.com/nidkil/akka-downloader)

If you prefer Futures, look at this example: [Scala Futures Downloader](http://sunilarora.org/scala-future-concurrent-download-example/)